# How to preserve a web service parameter, to consume it in another application?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, json, ajax

My application has a username textbox and an ASP web service.

I want to send the input value to this web service. Then I want to consume it in another, different application.

My question is: How can I preserve the value of parameter in the web service, so I can use it in another application?

Comment: when i login to system i wanna send username value and send it web service  and then reserve it for a while to consume this value in another system

Comment: Which technology is your system written in? Can you give specifics?  What have you tried, and what happened when you tried it?  Also, please fix confusion by editing your question, not adding comments to it.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited the question to have separate paragraphs, making it easier to read. I also replaced "reserved" with "preserved", which I think is what you mean. Please check.